# How to get max score full records from table?

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

My table is:

```
╔════╦════════╦════════════╦════════════╦════════╗
║ ID ║ TESTID ║ SESSIONID  ║ TOTALSCORE ║ USERID ║
╠════╬════════╬════════════╬════════════╬════════╣
║  1 ║     10 ║ 55cff3fbfs ║        250 ║    972 ║
║  2 ║     10 ║ 55cff3fbfs ║        440 ║    972 ║
║  3 ║     11 ║ 66fdf3fbfs ║        500 ║    972 ║
║  4 ║     11 ║ 66fdf3fbfs ║        700 ║    972 ║
║  5 ║     12 ║ 77ksfjskfs ║        800 ║    972 ║
║  6 ║     12 ║ 77ksfjskfs ║        700 ║    972 ║
║  7 ║     13 ║ 8fsfskffsf ║        900 ║    972 ║
║  8 ║     13 ║ 8fsfskffsf ║        750 ║    972 ║
╚════╩════════╩════════════╩════════════╩════════╝
```

I need to get maxscore full rows with by giving the userid

Result would be:

```
id  TestId sessionId     TotalScore   UserId
---|-----|------------|------------|---------
2  | 10  | 55cff3fbfs |     440    | 972
4  | 11  | 66fdf3fbfs |     700    | 972
5  | 12  | 77ksfjskfs |     800    | 972
7  | 13  | 8fsfskffsf |     900    | 972
```

So Please help me.......how to write the query/stored procedure in MYSQL

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idea of having a subquery is that it gets the greatest `totalScore` for each `TestID`. The result of which is then joined to the table itself provided that it match on the following condition, that the `TestID` and greatest `TotalScore` from the subquery matches to the values on the original table.

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    tableName a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT TestID, MAX(TotalScore) maxScore
            FROM tableName
            GROUP BY TestID
        ) b ON  a.TestID = b.TestID AND
                a.TotalScore = b.maxScore
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7d9bb/1)

The Output

```
╔════╦════════╦════════════╦════════════╦════════╗
║ ID ║ TESTID ║ SESSIONID  ║ TOTALSCORE ║ USERID ║
╠════╬════════╬════════════╬════════════╬════════╣
║  2 ║     10 ║ 55cff3fbfs ║        440 ║    972 ║
║  4 ║     11 ║ 66fdf3fbfs ║        700 ║    972 ║
║  5 ║     12 ║ 77ksfjskfs ║        800 ║    972 ║
║  7 ║     13 ║ 8fsfskffsf ║        900 ║    972 ║
╚════╩════════╩════════════╩════════════╩════════╝
```

Comment: Thanks you very much Kuya John. It was great help to me.